# Deploy windows application with database file

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have deployed my windows application in the client machine. But when I run the application, it crashes due to wrong connection string. In connection string, i have given datasource="./sql/myserver-name". The client machine has no sql server installed. So how can I make my application run on client machine with a correct string?